# How to join two dataframes together

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two dataframes.

One is coming from groupBy and the other is the total summary:

```py
a = data.groupBy("bucket").agg(sum(a.total))
b = data.agg(sum(a.total))
```

I want to put the total from b to a dataframe so that I can calculate the % on each bucket.

Do you know what kind of join I shall use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.crossJoin` then you will get the total from `b` added to all rows of df `a`, then you can calculate the percentage.

**`Example:`**

```
a.crossJoin(b).show()
#+------+----------+----------+
#|bucket|sum(total)|sum(total)|
#+------+----------+----------+
#|     c|         4|        10|
#|     b|         3|        10|
#|     a|         3|        10|
#+------+----------+----------+
```

---

Instead of **`CrossJoin`** you can try using window functions as mentioned below.

```
df.show()
#+-----+------+
#|total|bucket|
#+-----+------+
#|    1|     a|
#|    2|     a|
#|    3|     b|
#|    4|     c|
#+-----+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *
import sys

w=Window.partitionBy(col("bucket"))
w1=Window.orderBy(lit("1")).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize,sys.maxsize)

df.withColumn("sum_b",sum(col("total")).over(w)).withColumn("sum_c",sum(col("total")).over(w1)).show()
#+-----+------+-----+-----+
#|total|bucket|sum_b|sum_c|
#+-----+------+-----+-----+
#|    4|     c|    4|   10|
#|    3|     b|    3|   10|
#|    1|     a|    3|   10|
#|    2|     a|    3|   10|
#+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also collect()  as you will return to the driver just a simple result

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("select 'A' as bucket, 5 as value union all select 'B' as bucket, 8 as value")
df_total = spark.sql("select 9 as total")
df=df.withColumn('total',lit(df_total.collect()[0]['total']))

+------+-----+-----+
|bucket|value|total|
+------+-----+-----+
|     A|    5|    9|
|     B|    8|    9|
+------+-----+-----+

df= df.withColumn('pourcentage', col('total') / col('value'))

+------+-----+-----+-----------+
|bucket|value|total|pourcentage|
+------+-----+-----+-----------+
|     A|    5|    9|        1.8|
|     B|    8|    9|      1.125|
+------+-----+-----+-----------+
```